# QT Creator - plugins error messages

Tags: qt-creator

I have installed QT Creator 2.8.1. When it starts pop-up window shows : 
QT Plugins loader messages : The following plugins have errors and cannot be loaded
**List of plugins **
All of them have the same structure of message. For example : 
 Cannot load plugin because dependency failed to load: CppTools(2.8.1)

Does anyone have idea how to resolve this?

Thanks...

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS...

Comment: I also cannot make any project or open existing (I need to make C++ projects )